# Google Location history showing me in another continent? Did someone hack me?

Tags: google-location-history

I've just found out about Google Location history and it correctly displays all the places I've been to in Bolivia to-a-T. Really accurate.

What concerns me is that there is a dot in Singapore! I've never been anywhere near that country. Not even 2000 miles near.

[image: biking in Singapore...]

My question is, if someone logged into my account from that country, would that dot load from there? Should I change my passwords ASAP?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

From a security standpoint, it wouldn't hurt to change your passwords. I like LastPass - it keeps track of all my passwords and all I have to keep track of is ONE master key. It plugs in to your browser for quick access to sites.

Also, for added security on your Google account, turn on 2-factor (2-step) authentication. It should be under your account settings under security. Basically, it will ask you for your phone number (mobile) and you will get a text when you attempt to login to your Google account/services, this way if your password ever gets hacked, your account is still safe as long as you maintain control of your mobile phone. Hope this helps bud.

Here is the link to Google's 2 factor authentication landing page: [Google 2-step authentication](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/)